# Making an AJAX request with jQuery from PhoneGap app to Node JS server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, cordova

I've been looking around on the internet to see a real example of a jQuery AJAX request to a Node JS server, but can't find it.

So normally a jQuery AJAX request to a PHP server looks like this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({url: "http://www.example.org/myphpfile.php", success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }});
});
```

But how does this JS code look when a request must be made to a Node JS server? I've not seen any example that has a URL to a .js file on the server, but we do include a URL to a PHP file when a request is made to a PHP server.

So in short, what does a jQuery AJAX request to a Node JS server look like? Or are there any additional libraries or frameworks needed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS dosent work like that.

You set up and start the server on a port let say http://localhost:3000 and you send all request to it.

You can use a web application framework like Express to define routes more like `.htaccess` in php does. You setup functions on those routes.

So a typical call to a NodeJS looks like

`http://localhost:3000/route1`

route1 isn't a file its a route configured by a web application framework like Express to perform a task (or function) when the route is reached

So jQuery has nothing to do with it. You can still use it has it was just let url point to the route defined by Express

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({url: "http://www.example.org/getWhatever", success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }});
});
```

This tutorial will help https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters

This Book is great www.packtpub.com/web-development/mean-web-development

Comment: Okay, so I can't use jQuery AJAX to perform such a request to the Node server? Do I have to use something like Express? I was thinking about using MEAN stack, but actually hoped it could be achieved by just using Node JS on the server and jQuery on the client side to connect to it. *UPDATE: Okay, thanks for the example.